# Cannot Successfully Generate Model files Using Amplify for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-android

**Expected Results** 
Java classes for the models in `schema.graphql` are created.

**Actual Results**
I get this message:

> Error: No AppSync API configured. Please add an API

**What I have tried**

As suggested in [the Amplify API documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api), have tried to execute `amplify codegen models` from the project directory.

As suggested in [the Amplify Getting Started guide](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start), I have tried to execute the Gradle `modelgen` task from Android Studio.

**Information About the Project**

Executing `amplify status` shows the AppSync API is configured for the project:

```
    Current Environment: dev

    | Category | Resource name           | Operation | Provider plugin |

    | -------- | ----------------------- | --------- | --------------- |

    | Api      | THIS_IS_MY_RESOURCE NAME| Create    |                 |

    GraphQL endpoint: MY_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT
```

`amplifyconfiguration.json` and `awsconfiguration.json` are in `app/src/main/res/raw`.

I created the AppSync API from the AWS console and added it to the project with the following commands:

```
amplify init

amplify add codegen --apiId xxxxxxxxxxx
```